# How to get mtp tools to mount my phone?

Tags: debian, android, mtp

I've got Debian 8.5 running on top of Chrome OS, I plug in my Galaxy On5 and ChromeOS recognizes it instantly, Debian doesn't. I have mtp tools installed, and when I run mtp-detect I get the following output:

```
Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.
libmtp version: 1.1.8

Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Samsung: Galaxy models (MTP) (04e8:6860) @ bus 1, dev 10
Attempting to connect device(s)
ignoring libusb_claim_interface() = -6PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open
session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
inep: usb_get_endpoint_status(): No such device
outep: usb_get_endpoint_status(): No such device
libusb_open() failed!: No such device
LIBMTP PANIC: Could not init USB on second attempt
Unable to open raw device 0
OK.
```

Answer (score 1):

[There is](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mtp-tools&exact=1) a newer version of *mtp-tools* availible in backports, so you could try if it resolves the issue.

Comment: It still does not work on Debian 11 with a Galaxy S9+ (libmtp version: 1.1.17)

Answer (score 1):

Running `mtp-detect` was giving me an almost identical error.

After reading through [the following bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=921559), I was able to resolve the problem by removing the following packages:

```
sudo apt remove gvfs-backends
sudo apt remove gvfs
```

Running `mtp-detect` now gives detailed information about the phone, instead of just detecting it is a Samsung Galaxy MTP device.

I can also browse the device in KDE with Dolphin file manager (impossible before, supposedly due to the conflict with the GNOME gvfs).

*OS is the current version of Debian 11 Buster (libmtp version: 1.1.17), and phone is a Samsung Galaxy S9+.*

Comment: For those like me who wanted to know a bit more about this solution, `gvfs` is the Gnome Virtual File System: [arch man](https://man.archlinux.org/man/gvfs.7.en) / [what is gvfs and why](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38109/what-is-gvfs-and-why-should-i-want-it-on-my-system) / [arch file manager functionality](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/File_manager_functionality)